# How can I use environment variable in systemd timer unit?

Tags: timer, environment-variables, systemd

I have a systemd service to execute some shell.
I want to start this systemd service with a systemd timer.
I need to make the value for OnCalendar configurable for devops.

My first attempt was to provide a config file with key `TIMER_ONCALENDAR`,
load it as `EnvironmentFile` within timer unit and set default within timer unit in case the config file doesn't provide this key.

```
[Timer]
Environment="TIMER_ONCALENDAR=*-*-* *:00,15,30,45:00"

EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/my-config-file

OnBootSec=2min
OnCalendar=${TIMER_ONCALENDAR}
Unit=myservice.service
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My problem is, that the service is only run once and not every 15 min.
Is it even possible to use environment variable within timer unit and how?

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't sure about a directive, like `Environment=`, you can use `man systemd.directives` to find which man page the directive is documented.

In this case, it's documented in `man systemd.exec`, which explains that `Environment=` works in 4 types of unit files, but "timer" files are not one of them.

From reading 'man systemd.timer', you can find there's no mention of environment variables for systemd timers.

But you mentioned your end goal was to help with DevOps automation. That's possible.

Read about "drop-in" files in `man systemd.unit. You can create a file which contains *only* the`OnCalendar` directive, which will override or add to another base configuration file.

DevOps folks can easily automate adding or replacing the file that contains the `OnSchedule=` directive.